# Numba jitclass with multiprocessing

Tags: python, multiprocessing, pickle, jit, numba

I'm trying to use multiprocessing to speed up the performance of my code as well as using numba jitclass. There's jitclass instance contained in the jitted function, and this function is the target of the multiprocessing pool.
When I run the code, I got this error messages:

```
cPickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle <class 'numba.jitclass.boxing.MyClass'>: attribute lookup numba.jitclass.boxing.MyClass failed
```

I tried to run the code in python3, which also had the same issue:

```
_pickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle <class 'numba.jitclass.boxing.MyClass'>: attribute lookup numba.jitclass.boxing.MyClass failed
```

I even tried "pathos.multiprocessing" or "multiprocessing_on_dill" modules instead of the original "multiprocessing" module, neither of them worked.
How can I handle this problem? Thanks in advance.

Following is my test code.

```
import numba as nb
from scipy.integrate import odeint
import multiprocessing as mp

@nb.jit(nopython=True)
def odeSystem(x, t, a):
    v = a.func(x, t)
    return 1-x+v

@nb.jitclass([])
class B(object):
    def __init__(self):
        pass

spec = [("b", B.class_type.instance_type),("c", nb.f8)]
@nb.jitclass(spec)
class A(object):
    def __init__(self, b, c):
        self.b = b
        self.c = c

    def func(self, x, t):
        return 0

def odeSolve(x, t, a):
    sol = odeint(odeSystem, x, t, args=(a,))
    return sol

if __name__ == "__main__":
    a = A(B(), 3)

    from functools import partial
    initialx = range(10)
    ode = partial(odeSolve, t=range(0, 10), a=a)
    nProcess = 1
    pool = mp.Pool(nProcess)
    sol = pool.map(ode, initialx)
    print sol
```

If I run this, I got an error msg:

```
cPickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle <class 'numba.jitclass.boxing.A'>: attribute lookup numba.jitclass.boxing.A failed
```

Comment: Could you post the code that is creating the error?  You aren't going to get much traction without it.

Comment: Python multiprocessing doesn't share its memory between processes so it has to pickle the data you're sending to your process and then unpickle it on the other side. The error clearly states that it doesn't know how to pickle your object. You can use [`multiprocessing.Manager`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.sharedctypes.multiprocessing.Manager) for a queued data sync between processes, but it won't work with your custom objects unless you write translators. You should consider rethinking your strategy.